# is it possible to change a text font in style

Tags: android

I need to do a style in order to have all my bold texts in a specific font, and all my normal ones in an other. is it possible ?

i'm trying to build a style to do so, but there is no attribute to specify font type

Comment: it doesn't exists in android ? does it ?

Comment: `font-family` belongs to css/html, in android its `android:typeFace`

Comment: android typeface only supports normal,sans etc.. like written bellow

Comment: oops sorry ... I don't know how I even found this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can change font to a framework's pre-defined by using:

```
android:typeface="normal|sans|serif|monospace"
```

But in case you have your own custom font then I don't think you can do it from style or xml. The only way (as i know) to do it is via code:

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom_font.ttf"); 
txtyour.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: ok, so it's impossible to do so via style.xml to do it in the entire application and not only for each textviews

Comment: If you want to sue a custom font then yes, you have to set it for each TextView. But to make things fast, you can write a static method which takes TextView as parameter and set the font to your desired one

Comment: yes ok, but i have a second problem, i don't have a .dfont with bold and regular inside it. I have two separated fonts. so because i have some texts views with bold and regular texts inside it (with Html.fromHtml), i can't say the bold text use this font, and the regular one use this one

Comment: you can provide a flag for e.g. `isBold` in your custom method and decide your font according to this

Comment: but it will test the bold attribute of my textview right ? not if the text is suppose to display in bold ? I'm not sure I have understood